# Can't extract index list from yahoo finance

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, yahoo-finance, pandas-datareader

I'm trying to extract data from yahoo finance indices, but for some reason when I create a list of indices and try to extract it gives an error, but when I extract individually there is no error.
When I create a list with stocks the same code normally works.

```
import pandas_datareader.data as wb
import pandas as pd

tickers = ['^GSPC', '^IXIC', '^GDAXI']

index_data = pd.DataFrame()

for t in tickers:
    index_data[t] = wb.DataReader(t, data_source='yahoo', start='1997-1-1')['Adj Close']

print(index_data.head())
```

This error:
[image]

Comment: it is not to do with the list, this throws an error:  `wb.DataReader('^GSPC', data_source='yahoo', start='1997-1-1')['Adj Close']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but the yesterday date (2022-03-25) appears twice.

Fix with:

```
tickers = ['^GSPC', '^IXIC', '^GDAXI']

data = []
for t in tickers:
    sr = wb.DataReader(t, data_source='yahoo', start='1997-1-1')['Adj Close']
    sr = sr[~sr.index.duplicated()].rename(t)
    data.append(sr)
    
df = pd.concat(data, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                  ^GSPC         ^IXIC        ^GDAXI
Date                                               
1997-01-02   737.010010   1280.699951   2820.810059
1997-01-03   748.030029   1310.680054   2863.260010
1997-01-06   747.650024   1316.400024   2890.199951
1997-01-07   753.229980   1327.729980   2876.340088
1997-01-08   748.409973   1320.349976   2904.080078
...                 ...           ...           ...
2022-03-21  4461.180176  13838.459961  14326.969727
2022-03-22  4511.609863  14108.820312  14473.200195
2022-03-23  4456.240234  13922.599609  14283.650391
2022-03-24  4520.160156  14191.839844  14273.790039
2022-03-25  4543.060059  14169.299805  14305.759766

[6512 rows x 3 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

I edit the code to test for a single call like this:

```py
import pandas_datareader.data as wb
import pandas as pd

tickers = ['^GSPC', '^IXIC', '^GDAXI']

index_data = pd.DataFrame()

i = wb.DataReader('^GSPC', data_source='yahoo', start='1997-1-1')['Adj Close']

# for t in tickers:
#     index_data[t] = wb.DataReader(t, data_source='yahoo', start='1997-1-1')['Adj Close']

# print(index_data.head())

print(i)
```

and get the error message:

```
Exception has occurred: RemoteDataError
Unable to read URL: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/^GSPC/history?period1=852091200&period2=1648353599&interval=1d&frequency=1d&filter=history
```

which tells you that the error is not due the list (this seems to be fine), but from the call to the first item in the list.